# Controlar el orden de enfoque en mi página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quisera saber cómo se puede *controlar* el *comportamiento del enfoque*.

Por ejemplo, Tengo 3 *input* y un *button*:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" tabindex="1"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" tabindex="2"><br> Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" tabindex="3"><br>
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Cuando llego al *button* con el tabulador el foco se va para cualquier lado, por ejemplo a la barra de navegación.

¿Cómo puedo **mantener el enfoque** sólo en mis **inputs y button**?.

Comment: Encontre la solucion a mi problema en esta publicacion
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433638/tabindex-between-2-form-elements-only][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas HTML5 puedes usar el atributo [tabindex](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) en cualquier elemento HTML, y pudiendo de esta manera personalizar el órden de foco a tu gusto.

```html
<input tabindex="2" value="W3Schools"><br>
<input tabindex="1" value="Google"><br>
<input tabindex="3" value="Microsoft"><br>
<input tabindex="4" type="submit"><br>
```

Si usas HTML 4.01 solamente podrás aplicarlo a:

- `<a>`
- `<area>`
- `<button>`
- `<input>`
- `<object>`
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`

Para prevenir que al iniciar no esté seleccionado ninguno, puedes usar el atributo `autofocus` que se encargará de ponerle el foco al elmento deseado al momento de cargar, por sentido común solamente un elemento tendrá este atributo.

Ahora para que nunca se salga de esos elementos mediante tab, tendrás que usar el método `focus()` y usar la táctica de valor centinela.

Un valor centinela o bandera, es un valor que te permite saber si ya se cumplió alguna condición, en nuestro caso, que ya estemos seleccionando un elemento que no es de los que queremos que tengan foco.

Usando tabindex a nuestro favor, haremos que el primer y último elemento nos manden el foco a otro, en el caso del primero que nos mande al último, y en el caso del último al primero, esto debido a que para navegar entre campos mediante teclado se usa <kbd>Tab</kbd> para avanzar en una dirección, y <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> para avanzar en dirección contraria en el órden.

```html
<div id="centinela1" tabindex="1" onfocus="document.getElementById('ultimo').focus()"></div>
<input tabindex="3" value="W3Schools"><br>
<input id="first" tabindex="2" value="Google" autofocus><br>
<input tabindex="4" value="Microsoft"><br>
<input id="ultimo" tabindex="5" type="submit"><br>
<div id="centinela2" tabindex="5" onfocus="document.getElementById('first').focus()"></div>
```

### Nota

<sub>1</sub> El código proporcionado no necesita JQuery, pero si lo deseas puedes remplazar `document.getElementById('first').focus()` por `$('#first').focus()` para que use JQuery

<sub>2</sub> los ids de los centinelas no son necesarios, los puse únicamente para mostrar más identificables cuales son